# Can you set opacity for a css triangle that is cross browser compatible

Tags: css

I wish to create breadcrumbs that employ css arrows, and want to apply a gradient on the background, but have been unable to set a gradient for the css triangles themselves.

I'm wondering if I can set an opacity on the triangles , and then lay them over top of a div with the desired background gradient. This also has to be compatible down to IE7. So far no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Use a png for your breadcrumps and insert them via :before

Answer (score 0):

Use PNG image for the arrow. Arrow image must have transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what your looking  for would be to use an image.  IE7 I don't think supports opacity without some javascript manipulation. Use a gif or another type of image with transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set opacity or <=IE8

```
.triangle {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=80); // ie argh!
  opacity: 0.8; // standard browsers
}
```